# Using exported variables from required module with use strict

Tags: perl

I had previously had `use Foo;` to use a module I had written, and was using methods and variables from it which were exported using Exporter.pm.

I replaced the `use` with `require` to allow some flexibility on when the module was imported.  I now get dozens of errors all saying that the symbols "require explicit package name."

I know I could add the explicit method name for each, but there are quite a few.

Is there a way to alias these once so that afterwards I can use the symbol without explicit packages each time?

Comment: There's always `Foo::var` instead. Or using the BEGIN block.  Or use something like FindBin for compile time path evaluation

Comment: ***“I replaced the use with require to allow some flexibility on when the module was imported”*** Why did you do that? What flexibility do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***" I'm loading a module from a location specified in a config file, so it has to be done at run time"***

Okay, but it *doesn't* have to be done at run time so you're asking the wrong question

Do this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use constant CONFIG_FILE => '/path/to/config_file';

my $libs;

BEGIN {
    open my $fh, '<', CONFIG_FILE or die $!;
    chomp($libs = <$fh>);
}

use lib $libs;

use MyLib;    #  MyLib.pm is in the directory specified in config_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the symbols before they are encountered in the code by the compiler.

You can load the the symbols sooner.

```
use Foo;

sub moo { ... $SymbolImportedFromFoo ... }
```

You can compile the mention later.

```
eval(<<'__EOI__') or die $@;

    use Foo;

    sub moo { ... $SymbolImportedFromFoo ... }

    1;

__EOI__
```

Comment: I do not want to do things at compile time.  I'm loading a module from a location specified in a config file, so it has to be done at run time...

Comment: Re "I do not want to do things at compile time", Too bad. I repeat: You need to import the symbols before they are encountered in the code by the compiler.

Comment: I realize that, but surely there is some way to inform the compiler that I expect symbols X and Y to come from module Foo at compile time, even if I load the module at runtime?

Comment: @dsollen "I'm loading a module from a location specified in a config file" This sounds like it could be done in a `BEGIN` block, followed by `Foo->import`.

Comment: When you use a symbol you import, it doesn't "come from" the module. The symbol in the current package is used. You could create the variable in the current namespace, and hope it gets replaced when you later load Foo. But that's a very bad practice.